# Changing the name of an ion-icon that's used as an alternate Tumblr like button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tumblr

I'm using ion-icon as a customized Tumblr button for the theme I'm currently working on. My goal here is to change the name of the icon from "heart-outline" to simply "heart" (which is the name for the heart icon when it's filled) when the post itself has been liked or hovered, and back again to "heart-outline" if unliked.

Is there any way to do this at all?

My code heavily references (I mean straight-up copy-pasted with some modifications, lol) this [post by Shy Themes](https://shythemes.tumblr.com/post/154249052918/text-like-and-reblog-buttons).

Any help will be greatly appreciated; thank you.

```js
var $container = $('.posts');

function newElements() {
  var $newElems = $(newElements);
  var $newElemsIDs = $newElems.map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
  
  Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newElemsIDs);
};
```

```css
.likeb:hover {
  color: #c20404;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.likeb .like_button iframe {
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.likeb.liked+.b {
  color: #c20404;
}

ion-icon {
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 32px;
  margin-bottom: -2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts" id="{PostID}">
  <a class="likeb">{LikeButton}<span class="b"><ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>
</div>

<!--IONICON-->
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
 <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your function definition is invalid. See the error in the demo above. You probably want `function newElements()`. Please update the demo as needed to show the problem, and remove anything not relevant.

Comment: I would register a click event on the button. Unless you there is already a boolean for the heart icon to show if it has already been clicked or not. What does `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids` return? I think the only other issue might be that these buttons are embedded in iframes, I am sure I have seen that in the past, but I assume `Tumblr` is a global object that is available in the parent scope.

Comment: @lharby To my understanding, `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids` identifies whether the post has been liked or not, whether in the dashboard or in someone's blog or whatever, and returns that info to your theme. It's what the class `.liked` is for.

Comment: Let me know if that information is irrelevant here. The function of the like itself works fine, I just wanted to know if it's possible to change the heart icon from an outline to a filled one for accessibility and clarity purposes.

Comment: OK but you mean after it has been clicked right? Sorry I am not quite understanding. If it is a toggle to switch the class between the outline and the filled I can do that in an answer no issue (I am fairly sure). But if you just want to change it in the markup then can you not just alter `<ion-icon name="heart-outline">` to `<ion-icon name="heart">` I am guessing not as that won't indicate favourited post or not.

Comment: @lharby Yes, I do mean it after being clicked; sorry if that hadn't been clear. It doesn't even have to change to `name="heart"`, really, but I just couldn't figure out any other way to make it so the heart gets filled in. Again, it's mainly for accessibility purposes.

Comment: All done, answer below. Hope this is of some help @austin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I am completely rewriting my answer.

I added a reference to an older version of `ion-icons` (this has a heart and heart outline icon but allows us to change the content using css alone which we cannot do using the later ion-icons).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
```

I added this small piece of CSS:

```
.likeb .liked + .icon::before {
   content: "\f443"; // this will change to a filled heart icon
   color: #c20404;
}
```

I had to change the like button markup so it now looks like this:

```
<a class="likeb">{LikeButton}<i class="icon ion-ios-heart-outline"></i></a>
```

In addition I removed the click event I added in my previous answer as that is now redundant. The code starts (but is almost at the bottom of the current theme):

```
<!--LIKE BUTTON FILL-->
        <script>
            var likeButton = document.querySelectorAll('.likeb');
```

The whole code block is pasted here: [https://xxxxx.io/](https://xxxxx.io) I hope you can get this working, I can elaborate more on what I have done, but I am hoping it is fairly self-explanatory.

I asked about a code editor because you really want the file stored locally and then you can version it (make a back up etc). I think using an online editor is always going to be slightly disadvantageous, for instance in a code editor you can check the line numbers, edit find, copy, paste etc.

[image: Screenshot from VSCode IDE]

Comment: Hey, thank you! Both codes work just fine, the problem is that, as you can see in my CSS, I've got the Tumblr like button iframe, `.like_button iframe`, on top of the ion-icon itself, which is what the JQuery is for. I guess what I'm asking is, is there any way to get the data from `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newElemsIDs)` and use that to determine whether the heart should be filled or not, or would that not be possible? Thank you again, really. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah OK this will require a different approach, I will see if I can find anything, but there might already be some code out there to use googling custom like button tumblr etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this will work (I have only tested it using a hack) but there is also a pure CSS solution I have linked to, although this might mean some changes to your markup

Comment: I wouldn't mind testing something out for myself, so perhaps you could copy pasta the entire contents of your theme to a pastebin if possible?

Comment: Hope you don't mind I used another website (I'm kinda sh*t at naming, hahaha), or the emojis, or the fact that it's messy because I haven't really finished. [I pasted the code here](https://pastecode.io/s/cvosq67r). Thank you again!

Comment: @austin. I have some news. I have made a version of the blog work here: https://1001100.tumblr.com/ using only css. If this looks OK I can dump the whole theme in a pastebin (or similar). And I will add a new answer and try and explain. What are you using to edit your code in?

Comment: Oh, dude! That's fantastic! It looks great, yeah. And to answer your question, I use the built-in Tumblr theme code editor.

Comment: Yeah, dude, no, this makes total sense. Thanks again for all the work; really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, and also, would you mind if I asked to have my code removed afterwards? I don't exactly intend to share it around just yet. Thank you again!